# Help with Elementary Vector subspace proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble getting started with a proof of the following statement (I translated it from German, so bear with me):

"$V$ is a vector space and $U$ and $W$ are vector subspaces of $V$. Prove that the following two are equivalent:

a) $U \cap W = \{0\} $

b) Every $v \in U+W$ (with $U+W$ denoting the direct sum) can only be represented in one unique way as $v=u+w$ with $u \in U$ and $w \in W$."

I know that to prove equivalence (i.e. $a \Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ b), I have to show that $a \Rightarrow b$ and $b \Rightarrow a$ but I am having trouble getting anywhere. I attempted to assume $a$ is true and $b$ is false and prove by contradiction, but I couldn't get anywhere. Could you give me one or two hints so I can solve this on my own? Thank you! :)

Comment: Think about the basis for $V$ and $W$ and what it means to be a direct sum in terms of bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Assume $$v=u_1+w_1=u_2+w_2$$ with $u_i\in U$ and $w_i\in W$. Then

$$0=v-v=(u_1-u_2)+(w_1-w_2)$$

Now the first summand is in $U$ the second summand lies in $W$. Can you show that if the $u_i$ and $w_i$ are distinct that the intersection $U\cap W$ can't be trivial?

For the other direction: Assume 
$$v=u+w$$

and $x\in U\cap W$. Now consider

$$v=(u+x)+(w-x)$$

Comment: Thank you! :) This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;U\cap W=\{0\} : \text{if}\;\;u+w=u'+w'\;,\;\;u,u'\in U\,,\,w,w'\in W\;,\;\\
\text{then}& u-u'=w'-w\in U\cap W\;\ldots\\
(2)&\;\text{ Assume unique representation. If}\;\;x\in U\cap W\;,\;\text {then}\;\;x=x+0=0+x\in U+W\ldots \end{align*}$$

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much.